# TextClassifier AndroidX v.s Android P native: Have different results

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-9.0-pie

```
Artifact used (androidx.textclassifier:textclassifier:1.0.0-alpha02):

Version used:1.0.0-alpha02
```

I am working on an app which is based on TextClassifier. In order to support back-port on API 14 - 27, I use the AndroidX's TextClassifier, however, what disappointed me is that the predicting results of the NONE-P devices (API 14-27) are different from API 28 which is Android P. I figure out that internal of AndroidX is using the ">=P" for different solution which means, on 28, the library uses native ML solution (maybe).

**i.e:**

to predict the date-time text which is selected or passed into the app.

**On Android P:**

July 20, 1969, at 20:17    ->   inference: date or DateTime and the score: 0.9897

**<= O:**

July 20, 1969, at 20:17    ->  inference: other and the score: 0.9897

Is there any idea to let AndroidX's TextClassifier more AI-strong, like native Android P?

[Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139012023)

Comment: scores are the same there ....

Comment: @Blundell no, the inference type are different. on Android P, it is `data&time`, however, lower it is `other`.